# Cannot activate my static web page on my domain with AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have followed the AWS procedure to setup a new static web site on S3.

I have trouble shoot a number of issues and almost there I think.

Currently I can only reach my index.html test page by calling:

```
http://example.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/
```

from my web browser. But calling directly does not work:

```
http://example.com
```

It says the site cannot be reached.

Not sure where to look anymore. I've been waiting a few hours for any replicaton to happen. I believe I have the right region and alias setup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you bought the Domain name from AWS?

Basically S3 will only host the web content. The DNS entry would have to be updated in Route 53 if you have bought the domain via AWS.

Set your S3 url as Alias Target. That should just work.

[image]

OR

You need to set forwarding with your domain name provider where you bought it from.

Comment: I did not buy the domain from AWS, I bought it from GoDaddy. Then during the setup on AWS I received 4 DNS names that I used on GoDaddy console to transfer the domain to AWS DNS. Does that make sense ?

Comment: It looks like the DNS transfer has worked because: I have 2 domains: .me and .org. The main bucket is set to .org with the index.html file and the .me bucket just redirect to .org bucket. And this redirection is working because when i call my .me bucket the address changes to .org and the error is reported on .org. So the transfer works because this rule is only defined on AWS side.

Comment: I've never registered or transferred a domain to AWS, but I have used Route 53 to configure DNS for a domain. Have you done any DNS configuration in Route 53, or via the AWS domain registration system (if possible)? I believe this is required to get your custom domain to point to an S3 bucket.

Comment: Yes, i have created my Hosted Zones in Route53 and Created the Record set for each. For example for my main domain I have a type A, NS and SOA defined. The type A is set to IPv4 address and s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.

Comment: ok so you need to use your S3 web URL as a forwarding in Route 53. You can use the Alias for this ...